# How to view the User Entered data to the User in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using Wordpress and i ve a Form Plugin Name Ninja Form the form is saving the data from the User. But is it possible to show the User entered data to the same user when he search in search Field name : City and District .the user who belongs to corresponding city and district will display.

Comment: Please explain your question in more detail. Looks confusing.

Comment: My form contains the field Name , District , City , and Article there is another form below the main form Fields are District and City when another user enter city and district and click on the search button the search result will display all the user's Article from the searched district and city

Comment: You can get data from database based on userid and then you can display. but in search to display it. it will require too much custom code.

Comment: Yes, its possible. You need to do coding for that.

Comment: Any help to get Custom Codes???? @HelpingHands

Comment: Google is best way..:)